# Adding array into an certain array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to populate a nested array.

The first array `option_array` is created like this

```
var option_array =[];
if(!option_array.includes(row.option.option_id))
{
    option_array .push({
        option_id:row.option.option_id,
        option_name:row.option.option_name,
        max:row.option.max,
        min:row.option.min,
        value:row.option.value,
        price:row.option.price
    })
}
```

And now, I am creating another array *option_group*

```
var option_group=[];
if(!option_group.includes(row.option_group_id))
{
    option_group.push({
        option_group_id:row.option_group_id,
        option_group_name:row.option_group_name,
        max:row.max,
        min:row.min,
        option:option_array
    })
}
```

And I want to modify `option_group` whereas it will add only `option:option_array` where current `row.option_group_id` is equal to the `option_group.option_group.option_group_id`

Comment: Some more detail may help to understand your problem easily. What is in your option_array() and what is in your option_group() and what will be the output looks like?

Comment: what is option_group.option_group.option_group_id ?

Comment: I don't see how the first code could possibly work. You're pusing an object onto the array, but when you use `.includes()` you're just looking for a single value, not an object.

Comment: If you could give the JSON resperesntation of input and output, it would be helpful too.

Comment: You should be using `if (!option_array.find(o => o.option_id == row.option.option_id))`

Comment: Basically i am receiving this json http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceeINjWZvm?indent=2 and i want to match this json to this template http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bOulxhVolK?indent=2

Comment: Please refer to my last comment for the output @SifatHaque

Answer (score 1):

`.includes` checks if the array includes a certain item. Since you have an array of objects, you can't check if the array includes `row.option_group_id`. You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead. Get the object with `row.option_group_id` from the array. If it exists, update it. Else, add a new object to the array

```
const found = option_group.find(a => a.option_group_id == row.option_group_id)

if (found) {
  found.option = row.option_array; // update the found object
} else {
  option_group.push({
    option_group_id: row.option_group_id,
    option_group_name: row.option_group_name,
    ....
  })
}
```

Comment: How can I update the found object? For instance, I will add another array item into the object's existing array